# Access same file in Native Client and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c++, google-nativeclient

Is there a way to open a file in JavaScript and share that same file with a NativeClient module? I need direct file access in Native Client *and* JavaScript.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The HTML5 filesystems (both PERSISTENT and TEMPORARY) are shared between JavaScript and NaCl.   You can, for example, write files in JavaScript and then read them them native code.

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/
And: https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/devguide/coding/file-io

On the NaCl side you can also access the HTML5 filesystems with POSIX I/O operations by using the nacl_io library.

Comment: I would have to copy the entire file for this to work. Which could range from 700mb to about 14gb.